# How to hide App from Facebook Search while continuing to use Facebook's Analytics for Apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics, facebook-app-center

Currently I use "Facebook Analytics for Apps" to measure my iOS app activities and active users. However, I do not want my app to be visible in Facebook search (App section) which reveal the number of monthly active users.

If I turn off public in facebook developer page - [(please see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hP93.jpg). **Will my "Facebook Analytics for Apps" continue to work?**

PS: I am not using Facebook Login. All my users signup/login via phone number

Comment: I would assume that it does not depend on that, but you’d have to test it to be sure. // What does your app do? Setting it to not public can have effects on other stuff as well; for example any content created through it would not be visible to the public any more.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Analytics for apps will continue track your events, even if the app is not public.
I guess you are using Facebook Account Kit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit
for the user signup/login via phone number. By doing so, this will provide you better insights about your App users demographics.